# clang-tidy 10 is ignoring my NOLINT commands

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

`clang-tidy` v10.0.0 appears to ignore my `NOLINT` or `NOLINTNEXTLINE` instructions.  Using this trivial `compile_commands.json`:

```
[
{
  "directory": "/home/cmannett85/workspace/scratch/build",
  "command": "/usr/lib/ccache/g++-10 -g -Werror -Wall -Wextra -std=c++2a -o main.cpp.o -c /home/cmannett85/workspace/scratch/main.cpp",
  "file": "/home/cmannett85/workspace/scratch/main.cpp"
}
]
```

And this trivial source file:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    for (auto i : v | std::views::reverse) { // NOLINT
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Yields this `clang-tidy` output:

```
$ clang-tidy -p . --quiet ./main.cpp 
2 warnings and 6 errors generated.
Error while processing /home/cmannett85/workspace/scratch/main.cpp.
/home/cmannett85/workspace/scratch/main.cpp:8:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' and 'const __adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure<(lambda at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/ranges:3280:9)>' (aka 'const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptorClosure<std::ranges::views::(lambda at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/ranges:3280:9)>')) [clang-diagnostic-error]
    for (auto i : v | std::views::reverse) { // NOLINT
        ...
```

Now I can forgive the spurious error as C++20 ranges support may be lacking as it is so new, but why is `clang-tidy` ignoring my `NOLINT` instruction?

Comment: `NOLINT` suppresses clang-tidy warnings.  It does not suppress errors.

Comment: @Eljay Ugh. Now I've reread the documentation, it does specifically only say warnings. Is there are way of doing the equivalent for errors?

Comment: `clang-tidy -DCLANG_TIDY -p . --quiet ./main.cpp` and then `#ifndef CLANG_TIDY` ... `#endif` in the code.

Comment: @Eljay thanks, it's clunky but understandable. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clang-tidy` program can sometimes turn up false positives, or otherwise identify areas problematic that maybe (given your platform) are known implementation defined behavior that may not necessarily be compliant with the standard.

You can have `clang-tidy` ignore those sections by passing in a command-line define, such as `-DCLANG_TIDY`, and then use `#ifndef CLANG_TIDY` ... `#endif` blocks in your code that you want `clang-tidy` to ignore.

It is a pragmatic workaround.